# What is a suitable Lyapunov function for this system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

I have verified using the eigenvalue method that around $(0,0)$ the system

\begin{align}\dot x&=y - 3x - x^3 \\ \dot y &= 6x - 2y \end{align}

is stable. However, I have been trying to find a suitable Lyapunov function $V$ but from the expressions I have come up with so far, I cannot definitively deduce that the derivative is less than zero. I have tried the classical $V = x^2 + y^2$ and tried changing up the coefficients and exponents so that I can have some cancellations of the odd terms. It has been several hours now and still no luck. Any hints will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:
$$V(x,y)=\dfrac {y^2}2+ 3 x^2 \ge 0$$
Hence we have:
$$V'(x,y)=\left(\dfrac {y^2}2+ 3 x^2\right)'$$
$$V'(x,y)=\left( {y'y}+ 6x'x\right)$$
$$V'(x,y)= {y(6x-2y)}+ 6x(y-3x-x^3)$$
Regroup some termes into a square:
$$V'(x,y)=-2(y^2-6xy+9x^2)-6x^4 $$
$$V'(x,y)=-2(y-3x)^2-6x^4 \le 0$$
The derivative is zero only if:
$$V'(x,y)=0 \implies (x,y)=(0,0)$$

Comment: I might be wrong but I think this Lyapunov function has the same problem as my (now deleted) answer: $$\dot{V}=3x(y-3x-x^3)+\frac{y}{2}(6x-2y)=3xy-9x^2-3x^4+3xy-y^2.$$ There doesn't appear to be a way to make the two $3xy$ terms negative.

Comment: I don't need it to disapear it's part of the square @Axion004

Comment: Ah, yes you are correct (+1). Let me see if I can fix mine ...

Comment: Of course you can fix yours add a square thats all you need. Thanks I will also upvote yours once corrected @Axion004

Comment: Apology for not seeing that initially - I think that my answer is fixed now.

Comment: You still need to fix it @Axion004 because thats the terms with exponent 4 thats outside the square...But I upvote your answer

Answer (score 3):

Let $V(x,y)=6x^2+y^2$. Then
\begin{align}\dot{V}&=12x(y - 3x - x^3)+2y(6x-2y)\\&=
12xy-36x^2-12x^4+12xy-4y^2\\&=
-4(9x^2-6xy+y^2)-12x^4\\&=
-4(3x-y)^2-12x^4\\&< 0
\end{align}

for $(x,y) \ne (0,0)$.